# New relationship between exponential factors and entropy of a reaction?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetics

Consider the reaction $\ce{A <=> B}$. Let $k_f$, $E_A$, and $A$ denote the forwards rate constant, activation energy, and pre exponential factor, respectively. Let $k_r$, $E_A'$, and $A'$ denote the backwards rate constant, activation energy, and pre exponential factor, respectively. I seem to have determined the following relationship:

> $\ln{\frac{A}{A'}} = \frac{\Delta S}{R}$

First, is this a correct equation? Second, is this a known equation? I have not seen it in any of the textbooks that I have read. Third, is this a useful equation? I imagine it could be used to determine the ratio between the pre exponential factors from the entropy.

---

My derivation is below:

The equilibrium constant $K$ is equal the ratio of the forward and backwards rate constants $\frac{k_f}{k_r}$, so $\ln{(K)} = \ln{\left(\frac{k_f}{k_r}\right)}$. Furthermore, the Arrhenius equation expresses forward and backwards rate constants as $k_f = Ae^{-E_a/RT}$ and $k_r = A'e^{-E_a'/RT}$, where $A$ is the pre-exponential factor of the forward reaction and $A'$ is the pre-exponential factor of the reverse reaction. Substituting these expressions yields $\ln{(K)} = \ln{\left(\frac{Ae^{-E_a/RT}}{A'e^{-E_a'/RT}}\right)} = \ln{\frac{A}{A'}}-\frac{(E_a-E_a')}{RT}$.

In [Chapter 5 of Atkins' Chemical Principles 7th edition](https://www.macmillanlearning.com/college/us/product/Chemical-Principles/p/1464183953), the difference in activation energies of the forwards and backwards reactions $E_a-E_a'$ is equated to the reaction enthalpy $\Delta H$. Applying this relationship, we obtain: $\ln{(K)} = \ln{\frac{A}{A'}}-\frac{\Delta H}{RT}$.

It is also known, that since $\Delta G = -RT\ln{K} = \Delta H - T\Delta S$, $\ln{(K)} = -\frac{\Delta H}{RT} + \frac{\Delta S}{R}$.

Combining these two equations yields: $\frac{\Delta S}{R} = \ln{\frac{A}{A'}}$.

Comment: Your expression seems to be correct. I have never seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your expression is correct. It's nothing new though. Entropy of activation can be interpreted as part of the pre-exponential factor in the Eyring equation:

$$k=\bigg(\frac{k_B T}{h}e^{\frac{\Delta^\ddagger S^\circ}{R}}\bigg)\cdot e^{-\frac{\Delta^\ddagger H^\circ}{RT}}$$

Comment: In case it is not obvious to OP - note that $\Delta S_{rxn}$ is the difference between the two entropies of activation, so if you use this equation to rewrite the $\frac{A}{A'}$ term in the original question, the right side reduces to the left side. The Eyring form is much more informative and useful than the derived equation.